# Predefine the keys for a NSDictionary in a static library

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am creating a static library. In one of the inputs to a method, I am expecting the user to pass a `NSDictionary`.
I want to define a list of `NSString` constants that will act as `keys` inside the `NSDictionary`.

This is similar to Apple's `UITextAttributeFont`.

What is the best possible way of doing this?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you take a look at how Apple defined those constants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a constant string variables. You can do it by below way.

In .h file,

```
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString *const stringConstant;
```

In .m file,

```
NSString *const stringConstant = @"stringValue";
```

Now you can use variable stringConstant in your application which will refer to assigned values.

Comment: Was initializing the string in the wrong file!!
Nonetheless, thanks!! +1 for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create macros for the keys. In a header file, you can define the keys like so:

```
#define kSomeKey @"somekey"
```

Here's how you can use these constants:

For setting the object for a key in the (mutable) dictionary,

```
[dic setValue: someObject forKey: kSomeKey];
```

And for fetching the values:

```
[dic objectForKey: kSomeKey];
```

The advantage with using macros is that it will appear in the editor's suggestions provided that the header file has been imported.

Comment: Went with the `extern` string itself.
Nonetheless thanks for replying. +1 for replying.